# How to get style of clicked element - "currentTarget"

Tags: javascript, html, css

`currentTarget` works when I add `style` the html element. How can I access the `style` file of the clicked element without without adding `style` the html element?

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll(".all");

all.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let bgColor = e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor;
    console.log(bgColor);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  color: white;
  height: 2em;
  width: 15em;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  
  background-color: royalblue;
}

span {
  color: white;
  height: 2em;
  width: 15em;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">I'm a thin, big and insulated also soft, prickly box.</div>

<span style="background-color: black;" class="all">I am useless</span>
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/bcz0t6gx/⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣](https://jsfiddle.net/bcz0t6gx/%E2%81%A3%E2%81%A3%E2%81%A3%E2%81%A3%E2%81%A3)
⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣
⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) of the element and [`getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) to get the value of the CSS property:

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll(".all");

all.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let bgColor = window.getComputedStyle(e.currentTarget).getPropertyValue("background-color");
    console.log(bgColor);
  });
});
```

```css
.all {
  color: white;
  height: 2em;
  width: 15em;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  
  background-color: royalblue;
}

span {
  color: white;
  height: 2em;
  width: 15em;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">I'm a thin, big and insulated also soft, prickly box.</div>

<span style="background-color: black;" class="all">I am useless</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle` to find styles applied to an element. The following `getStyle` function makes this simple.

```js
const getstyle=function(n,css){
    let style;
    if( window.getComputedStyle ){
        style = window.getComputedStyle( n, null ).getPropertyValue( css );
    } else if( n.currentStyle ){
        css = css.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function ( strMatch, p1 ){
            return p1.toUpperCase();
        });
        style = n.currentStyle[ css ];
    } else {
        style='';
    }
    return style;
};



document.querySelectorAll(".all").forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    console.log( getstyle(e.currentTarget,'background-color') );
  });
});
```

```css
.all {//changed this to prevent console becoming weird
  color: white;
  height: 2em;
  width: 15em;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  
  background-color: royalblue;
}

span {
  color: white;
  height: 2em;
  width: 15em;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">I'm a thin, big and insulated also soft, prickly box.</div>
<span style="background-color: black;" class="all">I am useless</span>
```